# Testing Symfony2 Application in PhpStorm built in Webserver

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm as my IDE for developing a Symfony2 Application. In my early time development environment I want to use the built in Webserver of PhpStorm. But when I call:

> localhost:63342/Proj/web/app_dev.php

in my browser I get an error in a Pop-Up Dialog:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found). Do you want to open the profiler?

If I say "yes" it takes me to:

> localhost:63342/Proj/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/8d9fde

which brings up a 404 error page.

What am I doing wrong? Have I do something special for the built in Webserver?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm - that does sound more like a `Symfony Application` error, means something isn't working in your application. - (Though I am not sure whether this error can be caused by your Webserver)

Comment: Have you tried to use the Symfony built-in server (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html) available since 2.6?

Comment: The Symfony Application ist working fine. When I use the Symfony built-in Server I get no error and I can see the web debug toolbar of symfony, as I expected. When I publish it to my apache webserver in a later development stage, it works, too. Just the PhpStorm built-in server brings the error.